# Основная часть ответа

Tags: дефект, мобильная-версия

При формировании ответа на вопрос в мобильной версии приложения присутствует строка с текстом "Основная часть":

> [image: основная часть]

Вероятно это строка пролезает из формы вопроса:

> [image: мобильный вопрос]

т.к. при добавлении вопроса присутствуют ещё поля "Заголовок" и "Метки".
Однако при добавлении ответа упоминание про основную часть явно является лишним.

Озвучил проблему на [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284693/why-does-a-body-string-appear-above-the-answer-box), авось пофиксят как-нибудь.